# Meaning of the word "entrichten"

Tags: meaning

`Entrichten` habe ich nie gehört. Wie wird dieses Wort gebraucht? Kann man z.B. eine Rechnung entrichten? Hat es die gleiche Bedeutung wie das englische Wort `pay`?

Answer (score 9):

`Entrichten` bezieht sich immer auf einen konkreten Betrag oder eine Summe, man kann entsprechend eine Gebühr oder Steuern entrichten, aber keine Rechnung, die begleicht man.

Einen Rechnungsbetrag wiederum kann man entrichten.

For the interested English speaker:

`Entrichten` always refers to a specific amount or sum, accordingly you can use it as follows:

> Gebühren entrichten
>
> Geld entrichten
>
> Steuern entrichten

Not however with Rechnung, but, mind you, it is possible to do this:

> Einen Rechnungsbetrag entrichten

Comment: "Geld entrichten" war mir bisher nicht bekannt, es gibt zwar ghits aber ich würde es nicht gutes Deutsch nennen.

Comment: Schlimmstenfalls ist es unüblich. Mit "Geld entrichten" bewegt man sich definitiv im oberen Stilregister im Gegensatz zu beispielsweise "Kohlen abdrücken".

Comment: Als Ergänzung: "entrichten" geht normalerweile von unten nach oben (der Bürger entrichtet Steuern an den Staat, der Unterworfene entrichtet Tribut an den Unterwerfenden, man entrichtet Zölle oder Maut an die entsprechenden Autoritäten. "Bezahlen" ist eher unter Gleichgestellten (ich bezahle meinen Friseur, Handwerker oder andere mit denen ich einen Vertrag geschlossen habe). Insofern scheint "pay" mir nicht ganz dasselbe zu sein.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Das ist eine interessante Anmerkung, danke.

Comment: To the person who voted this down: I'd be quite interested why you chose to vote this down. It is common practice here to offer an explanation or a hint to make an answer better or more complete.

Comment: Ich habe zwar nicht downgevotet, aber Geld kann man nicht entrichten. Man verwendet Geld um etwas anders zu entrichten. Entrichten kann man (und das schriebst du auch richtig) Steuern und Gebühren, aber auch Abgaben, Zölle und ähnliche von Amts wegen vorgeschriebene Forderungen.

Answer (score 2):

In der Freien Wirtschaft (alles was nicht behördlicher/gesetzlicher Natur ist eigentlich, sondern auf ein freiwirtschaftliches Schuldverhältnis oder auf einen Vertag beruht bspw.)  werden Geldbeträge "bezahlt" oder "eingezahlt" oder "überwiesen".

Behördliche Schulden in geldlicher Form oder Verpflichtungen / Gebühren / Abgaben / Steuern wurden früher  "entrichtet". Schlicht: es ist ein "Obrigkeitlicher Begriff" einer zu leistenden oder geleisteten monetären Zahlungsverpflichtung. Heute geht aber auch hier der Begriffliche Trend eher hin zu "kundenorientierter Wortwahl" (also weg von typischem trockenen "Behördendeutsch", weil auch hier das Gegenüber von Bedeutung ist,  welches die Sachverhalte ja auch in Bezug auf persönliche Augenhöhe verstehen soll und nicht nur die Interessen einer Behörde zum Ausdruck kommen sollen, so wie diese im Gesetz und in niedergelegten Verfahrensvorschriften juristisch verfloskuliert oder formalisiert sind).

Answer (score -3):

"Entrichten" heisst auch nichts anderes als "bezahlen" - es ist nur ein sehr spezialisierter und recht formell/altmodisch/bürokratisch klingender Ausdruck dafür.

Comment: Eine Rechnung kann man aber bezahlen, jedoch nicht entrichten, strukturell gibt es also einen Unterschied und das ist genau der Unterschied, über den Gabrielle verständlicherweise gestolpert ist.